# A simple C# Web API for loggin IOT device

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

I have an Open EVSE car charger that I'd like to collect data from.  It can be used to push data to an emoncms server, but I want to collect the data via a C# Web API that I host.  I'm having trouble figuring out all the details of the various calls the device makes.

Is there a way to build a 'dumb' C# Web API with no methods that can be used to log the incoming requests regardless of what methods the requests may be targeting?  This will give me a tool to learn about the API and allow me to focus only on the methods I need to do basic logging.

There is some documentation for the API my charger is expecting to see (https://emoncms.org/site/api), but a dumb API to monitor all traffic from the device would have uses elsewhere.

Comment: Why not use a network logger like Fiddler or WireShark?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I've used both of these before, but don't they have to be installed on either the server or client that is being monitored?